# How to get document.currentScript.ownerDocument in <script type="module">?

Tags: html, ecmascript-6, web-component, es6-modules

How i can get ownerDocument in script type="module"?

```html
<template>
  text
</template>
<script type="module">
  let owner = document.currentScript.ownerDocument // is null
  
  // But i need get <template>
  
  let tpl = owner.querySelector('template')
</script>
```

Comment: Works for me on FF. Had to fix `</template>` closing tag though.

Comment: @Kaiido it not works on Chrome and other browsers

Comment: Indeed just tried in canary and it doesn't work. I have no source on who is right here, but FF executes `module` scripts before the `DOMContentLoaded` event, while chrome does it after... But at the end, in this example, `owner === document`.

Comment: So after testing a bit more canary, I would tend to a bug in how they deal with `defer` scripts. It should fire **before** `DOMContentLoaded`, but fails at it. Hence at this moment, `currentScript` is `null`

Comment: I haven't found how to achieve what you want. However, I can say that the described behavior is correct. In, fact Edge filled in a bug report for the opposite (currentScript was set). https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/9697735/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The spec clearly states that when using `<script type="module">` the `document.currentScript` property is set to `null` during execution. [See spec under "execute a script block"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#script-processing-model).

Which, of course, is obvious if using `src` attribute. The source has no way of knowing it will be called by a script tag and not an import statement (or both). When inlining the module there always is a script tag, but my guess is that they want to make the experience consistent.

If your document actually is the `window.document` that is still available as a global. Otherwise you have two options if you still want the script to be loaded as a module:

- Not the prettiest; create a global above the module and store the template.

  ```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  window.myTemplates = ((ns) => {
    const owner = window.document.currentScript.ownerDocument;
    ns.fancyButton = owner.querySelector("template");
    return ns;
  })(window.myTemplates || {});
  </script>

  <script type="module">
  const tpl = window.myTemplates.fancyButton;
  // ...
  </script>
  ```
- Don't write the template as a HTML template and instead as a ES/JS template. Your editor may not support highlighting literal HTML and linting of the tags is a problem.

  ```
  <script type="module">
  const tpl = window.document.createElement("template");
  tpl.innerHTML = `
    <strong>example</strong>
    <span style="background-color: rgba(127,127,127,0.6);">text</span>
  `;
  // ...
  </script>
  ```

Answer (score 2):

I came across the same problem yesterday and spent hours trying to figure it out and I think I might have a better solution using [dynamic import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import).

The trick is to create a loader script that is not a module like this:

```
<script src="loader.js"></script>
```

In loader.js:

```
var ownerDocument = document.currentScript.ownerDocument;

import('module.js').then((module) => {

     module.main(ownerDocument);

});
```

And your module:

```
function main(ownerDocument){

     console.log('Hello from the module!');
     console.log(ownerDocument);

}

export {main};
```

I hope this helps!